# PHP not parsing Javascript created HTML forms

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have HTML forms being created by Javascript. I also have regular forms not created by Javascript. When I submit the regular HTML form, the PHP script parses it just fine, but when I submit the Javascript created forms, it's not parsed. I can't for the life of me figure out why one parses, and the other one doesn't.

Javascript:

```
function addWeapon(){
    var weapsForm = document.createElement("form");
    weapsForm.setAttribute('name',"savefile");
    weapsForm.setAttribute('method',"post");
    weapsForm.setAttribute('action',"");

    var weapsName = document.createElement("input");
    weapsName.setAttribute('type',"text");
    weapsName.setAttribute('name',"textdata[]");

    var weapsNameQt = document.createElement("input");
    weapsNameQt.setAttribute('type',"number");
    weapsNameQt.setAttribute('name',"textdata[]");
    weapsNameQt.setAttribute('value',"0");

    var weapsNameSubmit = document.createElement("input");
    weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('type',"submit");
    weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('name',"submitsave");
    weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('value',"Done!");

    weapsForm.appendChild(weapsName);
    weapsForm.appendChild(weapsNameQt);
    weapsForm.appendChild(weapsNameSubmit);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(weapsForm);
}
```

And here's the PHP code which parses the HTML form no problem. I'd also like to add, the Javascript created HTML is exactly the same as the regular HTML.

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)){
    if ($_POST['submitsave'] == "Done!"  && !empty($_POST['filename'])) {
        foreach($_POST["textdata"] as $text){
            if(!file_exists($_POST['filename'] . ".txt")){
                $file = tmpfile();
            }
            $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] . ".txt","a+");
            while(!feof($file)){
                $old = $old . fgets($file);
            }
        file_put_contents($_POST['filename'] . ".txt", trim($text).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    fclose($file);
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help guys!

EDIT: I forgot to mention the "filename" field is in the HTML document, and is not created by Javascript.

<strike>EDIT: Also, the file is created on the server, but the forms are not being parsed.</strike>

EDIT: After messing with the code for a couple of hours, I realized it was in fact not parsing the "filename" field on the HTML document, but was parsing the Javascript form. Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: you are saying if filename is not empty..  I do not see a "filename" field in the javascript form.  There for it is evaluating to false I think.

Comment: The "filename" field is in HTML on the page, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Can you post your entire html?

Comment: I think if you inspected the element the problem was your html filename field was not actually encapsulated with in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form you are making with the Javascript is missing the filename field.. You either need to add the filename field in the Javascript for like below:

```
function addWeapon(){
    var weapsForm = document.createElement("form");
    weapsForm.setAttribute('name',"savefile");
    weapsForm.setAttribute('method',"post");
    weapsForm.setAttribute('action',"");

    var weapsName = document.createElement("input");
    weapsName.setAttribute('type',"text");
    weapsName.setAttribute('name',"textdata[]");

    var weapsNameQt = document.createElement("input");
    weapsNameQt.setAttribute('type',"number");
    weapsNameQt.setAttribute('name',"textdata[]");
    weapsNameQt.setAttribute('value',"0");

    var weapsfilename = document.createElement("input");
    weapsfilename.setAttribute('type',"text");
    weapsfilename.setAttribute('name',"filename");
    weapsfilename.setAttribute('value',"SomeFile.txt");

    var weapsNameSubmit = document.createElement("input");
    weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('type',"submit");
    weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('name',"submitsave");
    weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('value',"Done!");

    weapsForm.appendChild(weapsName);
    weapsForm.appendChild(weapsNameQt);
    weapsForm.appendChild(weapsNameSubmit);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(weapsForm);
}
```

Or you need to change your conditional in php not to be based on the filename like so:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)){
    if ($_POST['submitsave'] == "Done!") {
        // New code parsing the other fields since you are no longer grabbing a file
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I gues your `$_POST['filename']` is empty.
`empty()` function in php check is variable has some value. So if you do not choose your file it will return `true` ( empty ). Try to use `isset()` if you need to check is your input was sent.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it seems that you need to add following code in your javascript.

```
function addWeapon(){
var weapsForm = document.createElement("form");
weapsForm.setAttribute('name',"savefile");
weapsForm.setAttribute('method',"post");
weapsForm.setAttribute('action',"");

var weapsName = document.createElement("input");
weapsName.setAttribute('type',"text");
weapsName.setAttribute('name',"textdata[]");

var weapsNameQt = document.createElement("input");
weapsNameQt.setAttribute('type',"number");
weapsNameQt.setAttribute('name',"textdata[]");
weapsNameQt.setAttribute('value',"0");

var weapsFile = document.createElement("input");
weapsFile.setAttribute('type',"file");
weapsFile.setAttribute('name',"filename");
weapsFile.setAttribute('value',"0");

var weapsNameSubmit = document.createElement("input");
weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('type',"submit");
weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('name',"submitsave");
weapsNameSubmit.setAttribute('value',"Done!");

weapsForm.appendChild(weapsName);
weapsForm.appendChild(weapsNameQt);
weapsForm.appendChild(weapsFile);
weapsForm.appendChild(weapsNameSubmit);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(weapsForm);
}
```

And in php you need to print $_FILES instead of $_POST to get filename.